# I am using google map nearby places API in android. My code only shows the near by places

Tags: android

But i can not select each of them separately.
How can I select each of them separately by touching their marker and get their details. A in this function below a `json` `array` is used of 0-19(20) elements.

*I dont know how to use them to select each marker separately.*

```
private void parseLocationResult(final JSONObject result) {


    String id, place_id, placeName = null, reference, icon, vicinity = null;
    JSONArray rev;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    try {
        final JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray(RESULTS);//JavaScript Object Notation

        if (result.getString(STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase(OK)) {

            mMap.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject place = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                id = place.getString(SUPERMARKET_ID);
                place_id = place.getString(PLACE_ID);
                if (!place.isNull(NAME)) {
                    placeName = place.getString(NAME);
                }
                if (!place.isNull(VICINITY)) {
                    vicinity = place.getString(VICINITY);
                }
                latitude = place.getJSONObject(GEOMETRY).getJSONObject(LOCATION)
                        .getDouble(LATITUDE);
                longitude = place.getJSONObject(GEOMETRY).getJSONObject(LOCATION)
                        .getDouble(LONGITUDE);
                reference = place.getString(REFERENCE);
                icon = place.getString(ICON);


                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                markerOptions
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bluemarker))
                        .position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);


                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);



            }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonArray.length() + " found!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result.getString(STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase(ZERO_RESULTS)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not found in 5KM radius!!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "parseLocationResult: Error=" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implement `GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener` and Override `onMarkerClick` to detect click on marker

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    // on marker clicked

    if (marker.equals(this.marker)) {
         // on specific marker clicked
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you can compare lat and long of clicked  marker with your specific lat and long @ZiaAnsari

Comment: Actually it show the the details in the log when i click the marker now.

Comment: what you want to do exactly? you want start an activity when user clicked on marker , for example? @ZiaAnsari

Comment: yes. and show the details of that marker. Marker is any place actually. like restaurant,club,mosque etc.

Comment: if you have marker details on your own database, you can get details via searching on lat and long of clicked marker.
to get latlng you can use this code "LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();"

Comment: I am using web services api